# Create AppleScript for a program that isn't installed on the current computer

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to make two copies of an AppleScript, one that works for Entourage and one for out Outlook. I only have Entourage installed on the current computer.

According to the info on Microsoft's site, both applications have the same library of AppleScript commands, and I should be able to simply change the application name referenced within the script.

Changing:

```
Tell application "Microsoft Entourage"
```

to

```
Tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
```

Prevents me from saving the script because I don't have outlook installed on this computer. Is there any way around this? Do I need to use a text editor to edit the actual script file and change it there?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following work-around may do the trick. On the computer where Entourage is installed, a [using terms](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-DontLinkElementID_879) directive will let you compile the script, even if Outlook is not installed:

```
set theApp to a reference to application "Microsoft Outlook"
using terms from application "Microsoft Entourage"
    tell theApp
        get version
        ...
    end tell
end using terms from
```

Upon compiling and saving the script the AppleScript Editor will bug you about the missing Outlook application, but it will nevertheless produce a compiled AppleScript file (.scpt).

Answer (score 0):

Applescript is a pre-complied file format, meaning that every time you click "Save" it runs through a series of steps to ensure the script will work, but just short of actually running through the script's logic. Part of those steps is to look for the application to see if it exists on the Mac.

In short, if you want to save the script as an Applescript, you need the target application installed, otherwise you can save the script as a text file and move the file over to the target Mac to save as an Applescript over there.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to make one script that works with both Entourage and Outlook, without bugging you if one isn't found either when you compile or when you run. I don't have either Entourage or Outlook but it should work like this:

```
using terms from application "Microsoft Entourage"
    script theScript
        tell application "Finder" to try
            set theApp to application file id "Entourage's Bundle ID" as text
        on error
            set theApp to application file id "Outlook's Bundle ID" as text
        end try
        tell application theApp
            -- do stuff
        end tell
    end script
end using terms from
store script theScript in "MyScript.scpt"
```

"using terms from" is only relevant when compiling the script - it isn't needed when running, though for some reason you'll still get bugged if that app isn't found. So by wrapping it around a script object and then writing out that script to file, the resultant script will still run but won't contain "using terms from" and so won't bug the user.

For getting a reference to the right app, Finder can look for it by ID and simply error if it isn't found rather than bugging the user. You'll need to insert the proper ID's there, I don't know what they are.